Ubuntu 24.04 sound issue on Lenovo
Afternoon folks,
I have been checking all the stuff related to sound issues in Ubuntu 24.04 but I have not found fix for that. I have got installed the Ubuntu 24.04 on a Win 11 machine as Dual boot.
The problem consists that sometimes if I let the laptop without any action or change the music for example via Youtube, it will silence or make dummy sound (it is playing and I can hear the sound BUT the strength is missing there) until I type:
sudo alsa force-reload - only this one command always help and letting system go to sleep and awake him
I was able to type alsa-info during the issue and that created a report which can be useful:
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=b121d197bfaeaa6c774cb661764f4283a00108bb
If everything is OK the report is:
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=7be45f653872606772f519da0a5499408eabaacd
Not sure if this will help but I am trying to find a resolution for it...
Thanks in advance.
